# python code that change data in series or dataframe

Tags: python

Now I have one column data which is from dataframe. I want to make all data which is more than 200 and less than 880 become "1" not number 1. It is my code `y.values[y.values>=200,y.values<=880]=="1"`. But it is not work. It says too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed. I don't know why. I also tried `y.values[200<=y.values<=880]=="1"`. It also not work. I need help about this.

Comment: `[y.values[200<=y.values & y.values<=880]`

Answer (score 0):

```
y = pd.DataFrame([100, 199, 200, 201, 300, 400, 880, 881, 1000], columns=['Values'])  # see note below

y.Values[y.Values.between(200, 880)] = '1' # boundaries are included by default

# or
# y.Values[y.Values.ge(200) & y.Values.le(880)] = '1' # ge is >=, le is <=
# or
# y.Values = y.Values.apply(lambda x: '1' if 200 <= x <= 880 else x)
# or
# y.Values[(y.Values >= 200) & (y.Values <= 880)] = '1' # parentheses required because & has a higher priority than <= and >=
print(y)
```

Prints:

```
  Values
0    100
1    199
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      1
6      1
7    881
8   1000
```

**Note.** [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame